# SQL DELETE statement in C#

Tags: c#

I'm just asking for help.. it doesn't delete the row. .but i didn't encountered any error.. please help me..my code is:

```
private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtprn.Text == "" || txtdescription.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No selected file to be delete!", 
                            "Delete Data", 
                             MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,  
                             MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult answer;
            answer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", 
                                     "Delete Record",
                                      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                      MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
                                      MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

            if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                con.Open();
                com.CommandText = 
                   @"DELETE 
                       FROM tblsupply 
                      WHERE (prnumber = @prnumber AND         
                             description = @description)";

                com.Parameters.Clear();
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prnumber", txtprn.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtdescription.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted!");
                con.Close();
            }
            ClearFields();
            GridRefresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any exception is throwing?

Comment: Check the value of output. If it returns a positive number, that many records are deleted. If you get a -1 a rollback occurs at the sql server. `var output = com.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: What is the return value of the `ExecuteNonQuery` call. It should be the number of rows affected (in this case deleted)

Comment: Have you run through the code step by step, is it executing the sql command? Where are you declaring and instantiating the con and com objects? May we please see that code? Have you checked the CommandText that is generated at run time and tried executing that directly in SQL Server?

Comment: I think that deleting by columns which are not key columns can be the reason. Try select rows using the same values and check if select returns what you want. Maybe this query don't mach records to delete.

Comment: Careful with that AddWithValue [see here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). You are now declaring that `@prnumber` parameter to be some character type - is that what you need here?

Comment: Yeah better use Add and manually define the SqlDbType. Just a few more codes. AddWithValue is for lazy developers. [Opinion]

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of output. If it returns a positive number, that many records are deleted successfully. If you get a -1 a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Convert the txtprn to int as it looks like a number and you are passing as string.

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prnumber", Convert.ToInt32(txtprn.Text));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtdescription.Text);
var numberOfRowsAffected = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted!"+numberOfRowsAffected );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was suggesting not to delete a record based on user input. In your case, you should have an identifier that is not editable by user even more hidden value that your application is managing behind the scene. 
Scenario:

1. User is adding a new record (though GUI)
2. User is saving and the application should create a new id for it. The application.
3. Once loading the saved record, the application will retrieve the id too and save it somewhere behind the scene.
4. Once deleting the record (though GUI), the deletion will be done according to the id and not through the values in the textboxes.

In your current state, note that the deletion may not succeed in case that are spaces for example so you cannot rely on those texts for deletion.

Answer (score -3):

Place this try catch so you'll know the error

```
 try
    {
    DialogResult answer;
                answer = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", "Delete Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);

                if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    com.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tblsupply WHERE (prnumber=@prnumber AND description=@description)";
                    com.Parameters.Clear();
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prnumber", txtprn.Text);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtdescription.Text);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted!");
                    con.Close();
                }
                ClearFields();
                GridRefresh();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ex.Message.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: He said there is no error, so I assume it will not catch anything. This is not an answer.

Comment: Yes the query will execute, but there's an error behind it during transction.. so this answer probably is just a suggestion, and might help him to solve the answer, but i understand the downvotes.